# Get <td> values only in specific rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, rows

I have a table (id="docsTable") whose rows look similar to this:

```
<tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="docsToAddToClass[]" value="35" /></td>
    <td>Document Title</td>
    <td>Document Description.</td>
</tr>
```

I need to iterate through the table, determine which checkboxes the user has checked, and for the rows with a checked checkbox, grab the value for the first  and the text for the next two.

I don't need to build a collection: Within each iteration I want to change some elements elsewhere. That's not the hard part (for me). It's trying to figure out how to iterate through the table and select only the s with checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#btnTest').click(function(){
                $('#docsTable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                    var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
                    alert($row.find('td:eq(0) input').val());
                    alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
                    alert($row.find('td:eq(2)').html());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="docsTable">
        <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="docsToAddToClass[]" value="35" /></td>
            <td>Document Title 1</td>
            <td>Document Description.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="docsToAddToClass[]" value="36" /></td>
            <td>Document Title 2</td>
            <td>Document Description.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="docsToAddToClass[]" value="37" /></td>
            <td>Document Title 3</td>
            <td>Document Description.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type='button' id='btnTest' value='Get Rows' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! A working example in less than 5 minutes! And exactly what I was looking for! I've been a long-time searcher of Stackoverflow but this is my first time posting a question here. You guys rock!

Comment: @eventide - Glad we were able to help! The best way to give back is to browse the site and answer some questions. Not only will you be contributing to the community, but you can use the reputation you gain and your profile as part of your resume. Anyway... Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something along this line:

```
$('tr > td:first-child > input:checked').each(function() {  
    // $(this).val() is the value of the input
    // $(this).parent().siblings() will refer to the two <td>'s  
    // You can also try other traversal methods like $(this).parent().next()
});
```

Hope this works and helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#docsTable > tr > td > input:checked').each(function(i,element){

var el = $(element);
alert( el.val() );
alert( el.parent().siblings(':eq(0)').html() );
alert( el.parent().siblings(':eq(1)').html() );

});
```