# check for a value in all textboxes in a row

Tags: jquery

I keep getting an object returned when I check if any textboxes have a value in the supplied row or it only checks the first textbox.  I want to pass a row to the chkblock function and get a true back if any of the textboxes has a value.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Roy

You can see the entire thing here: http://jsbin.com/igaror/1/edit

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
      article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
      menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /><input id='1' class='name' type='hidden' value='test 1'/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="room" value="44"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /><input id='1' class='name' type='hidden' value='test 2'/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="room" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>

   $('.room').change(function() {
     var row = $(this).closest("tr");
     var block = false; //row.find(":text.room").val() !== "";
     var vname = row.find(":input.name").val();
     block = chkblock2(row);
       alert("name: " + vname + " block:" + block);
     if(vname == "test 1"){
       $(this).closest("table").find(":input.name").each(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == "test 2"){
           var row = $(this).closest('tr');
           row.find(":text").attr("disabled",block);
           row.find(":text").val("");
              }
     });
             $(this).closest("table").find(":input.name").each(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == "test 1"){
           $(this).closest("tr").find(":text").attr("disabled",false);
           //$(this).val('');
              }
     });

     } else if(vname == "test 2"){

       $(this).closest("table").find(":input.name").each(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == "test 1"){
           var row = $(this).closest('tr');
           row.find(":text").attr("disabled",block);
           row.find(":text").val("");
              }
     });


        $(this).closest("table").find(":input.name").each(function() {
         if ($(this).val() == "test 2"){
           $(this).closest("tr").find(":text").attr("disabled",false);
           //$(this).val('');
              }

     });  

     }



   });

function chkblock(row){
  return row.find("input:text:not(:empty)");
}

function chkblock2(row){
  row.find(":input.room").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== "" ){
      return true;
    }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the relevant part of the code / where is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310594/get-td-values-only-in-specific-rows-using-jquery ? might help `:)`

Comment: The problem is with the var block.  I want it to check if any of the textboxes have a value in the var row.  I tried the commented out code next to the block var and the two functions at the bottom chkblock and chkblock2 without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use data-binding for that: use JSON objects and knockoutjs for get the input values instead of filtering through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing a loop through the td's with this updated function.  Thanks to everyone for their input.

```
function chkblock2($row){
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; ++i){
    if($row.find("td:eq(" + i + ") input.room").val() !== ""){
      return true;
    }
  }
    return false;
}
```